# Newline in windows

Tags: windows, newline, xilinx

When I use `\r\n` in Windows, to print a newline in a file, it works if the file is `<anyfile>.v`, i.e., it's extension is `.v`. But if the file extension is changed to `.ucf`, it starts printing some garbage. I do it through Java code. Any help?

`.v` is a verilog file and `.ucf` is a Xilinx propietory constraints file. Both are handled by Xilinx software.

On running,

```
import java.io.*;
public class ucf {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
FileWriter output = new FileWriter("sample.ucf");
output.write("foo\r\n\bar\r\n");
output.close();
}
}
```

garbage is produced.

Comment: Please tell us what `.v` and `.ucf` files are. Presumably they're handled by a specific program, which gets to decide what to do with them.

Comment: Not true. Java does not care about file extensions.

Comment: `.v` is a verilog file and `.ucf` is a Xilinx proprietory constraints file. They both are handled by Xilinx software.

Comment: @kamalbanga Then this is a case for Xilinx support, not for SO.

Comment: @Ingo but you yourself said that Java does not care about file extensions.

Comment: @kamalbanga Right, it doesn't. So, there **will** be "\r\n" in the Xilinx file, but the problem seems to be that Xilinx cannot handle this.

Comment: @Ingo but i am opening this file in a text editor

Comment: So where does Java play into this??

Comment: @MadConan sorry i will remove java tag

Comment: @kamalbanga Please provide a tiny program that creates an .ucf file and prints "foo\r\nbar\r\n", and then lets see how it is garbage.

Comment: @kamalbanga And if you now change the filename to "sample.v" the file contents is different? Have you verified this?

Comment: @Ingo, yes i verified this and sorry for late answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are writing to a [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) or a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Writers require a [CharSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (eg UTF-8) to convert characters to binary data. If you didn't explicitly provide a charset when constructing your Writer, the [JVM's default charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) will be used.

I'm guessing that you write the file using one charset and Xilinx is reading the file using a different charset thus causing garbage in Xilinx.

Note that `\r\n` is not standard across all operating systems. To get the OS's newline at runtime you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of hard coding.

Comment: +1 Nicely guessed. I whish posters would expend half of that energy to formulate their questions and provide examples of code that behaves wrong.

Comment: Yeah, since I usually use raw streams, I didn't think of the whole Writer issue.  Good call.

Comment: @lance thanks for `System.getProperty`, exactly what i needed :)